# What is the difference between the three sentences in the body?

Tags: grammar

What made you think that I love you

Why did you think that I love you

How did you think that I love you

What is the difference between these three sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> What made you think that I love you?

"What happened that caused you to think that I love you?"

> Why did you think that I love you?

"For what reason did you start thinking that I love you?"

> How did you think that I love you?

This is one a bit trickier. This would often (but not always) be used to show surprise. "How could you possibly think that I could love you?" or a bit clearer, "You thought I loved you? How could you think that?". I don't know if what I am trying to say is getting across, but I really can't think of a way to say it without using "how".

Answer (score 1):

These are *mostly* synonymous, but there are a few differences:

> What made you think that I love you?

*What* is used to specify something (be it a person, place, thing, idea, etc.) as a cause.

"What event or thought influenced you to think that I love you?"

> Why did you think that I love you?

*Why* is used to specify a *motive* or *reason* behind an action.

"What reason do you have that support the notion that I love you?"

> How did you think that I love you?

*How* is used to specify what *methods* were used in the application of the verb.

**Either**

"How was it possible for you to think that I loved you?"

**OR**

"In what ways did you think I love you?"